# Syntax error in awk while sorting the fields

Tags: awk

Hi all,
                  I am using awk in order to print  the output, sort them and then store it in a file but when I insert the sort command I am getting a syntax error.. Here is my below code .. Could you ppl please let me know If I am going the things correctly

CODE

`id !~ /^\s*$/){print id,ip[id];}|sort -k 1 > "file"} for (key in h) {split(key,values," "); if(values[1] !~ /^\s*$/ && values[2] !~ /^\s*$/){print values[1],values[2],h[key]}|sort -k 1 -k 2 > "file"}}`

`awk:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                ^ syntax error`

Comment: Can you please supply the whole command line, *and* the complete error message - it'll make it easier to help.

Comment: Ya sure I will work on the same

Comment: No I have resolved all the things.. Without sort command it works good

Comment: My script is big and hence pasting the part of the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work, change:

```
... | sort -k 1 > "file" } ...
```

to

```
... | "sort -k 1 > file" } ...
```

and the same change for your other `sort`. I.e., enclose your whole `sort` command inside double quotes.